# Get characteristic gatt from Notification

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm using RxAndroidBle with kotlin.
So far I could set multiple notifications and i'm receiving them.

How can i map the notification to it's specific characteristic?

So far:

```
enter code here connectionObserver
            .flatMap { rxBleConnection ->
                rxBleConnection.discoverServices().flatMap { services -> services.getService(ServiceUUID).map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics) }
                        .flatMapObservable { s -> fromIterable(s) }
                        .flatMap { characteristic -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristic)
                                .flatMap{ notificationObservable -> notificationObservable}}
            }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{notification->notification}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those strugling with kotlin and RxAndroidBluetooth,  after some work I make it to work, so the original code looks like

```
enter code here  connectionObserver
            .flatMap { rxBleConnection ->
                rxBleConnection.discoverServices().flatMap { services -> services.getService(ServiceUUID).map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics) }
                        .flatMapObservable { s -> fromIterable(s) }
                        .flatMap { characteristic ->
                            rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristic)
                                    .flatMap { notificationObservable -> notificationObservable.flatMap { result -> Observable.just(result).zipWith(fromArray(getBytesFromUUID(characteristic.uuid))) } }
                        }

            }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { notification -> onNotificationReceived(notification)
            }
```